# Сборка React-модуля при запуске mvn package

Tags: java, node.js, spring, maven, jar

У меня есть проект написанный на Spring Framework, внутри которого находиться модуль написанный на React. Вопрос по поводу того, как можно настроить автоматический запуск `npm install` и `npm run build` при запуске команды `mvn package`, чтобы по итогу в .jar попадал этот самый модуль со всеми зависимостями от Node.js.

Если формулировка не очень понятная, то говорите, я добавлю больше подробностей.

P.S. Пробывал пользоваться npm-maven-plugin, но не разобрался как его настроить правильно.

Comment: Вы знакомы с хипстером Джи? https://www.jhipster.tech/
Не призываю использовать, но сгенерите проект и посмотрите там как это делается :)))

Comment: Не знаком. А можно в рамках maven с помощью плагинов это настроить?

Comment: О том и речь. В хипстере генерируем проект - из предложенных вариантов выбираем maven и React. Остальное не сильно важно. После генерации открываем pom.xml и смотрим как там работает.

Comment: О, крутяк. Как попробую, отпишусь

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил, использовав `frontend-maven-plugin` и `maven-resources-plugin`, в итоге получились такие плагины в `pom.xml`

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/<путь до модуля React></workingDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install node</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-yarn</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
                        <yarnVersion>${yarn.version}</yarnVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>yarn install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>yarn</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>yarn build</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>yarn</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>build</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/static</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}/<путь до модуля React>/build</directory>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```